# Enum value to checkbox in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am am working on one feature roles and permissions. i want to give best work on this. i have some doubt.
My Enum Class is

```
public enum Roles
    {
        UserCreate = 1,
        UserEdit = 2,
        UserDelete = 3,
        UserAssign = 4,
        UserView = 5,

        TeamsCreate = 6,
        TeamsEdit = 7,
        TeamsDelete = 8,
        TeamsAssign = 9,
        TeamsView = 10,
    }
```

My Data is

```
public RolesViewData : MasterViewData
    {
       Public List<Roles> Roles {Get;Set;}
    }
```

View is

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <label>Permissions: <span>*</span></label>
   <input id="chkCreate" name="chkCreate" type="checkbox"/> User Create 
   <input id="chkEdit" name="chkEdit" type="checkbox"/> User  Edit
   <input id="chkDelete" name="chkDelete" type="checkbox"/> User Delete
   <input id="chkAssign " name="chkAssign" type="checkbox"/> User Assign 
    <input id="chkView" name="chkView" type="checkbox"/> User View

 <input id="chkTDelete" name="chkTDelete" type="checkbox"/> Team Create 
   <input id="chkTEdit" name="chkTEdit" type="checkbox"/> Team Edit
   <input id="chkTDelete" name="chkTDelete" type="checkbox"/> Team Delete
   <input id="chkTAssign " name="chkTAssign " type="checkbox"/> Team Assign 
    <input id="chkTView" name="chkTView" type="checkbox"/> Team View
</div>
```

Then which one do we need to for checkbox? either Enums? can you suggest me the best approach

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as opinion based.  But with any Roles system, where a user can have multiple roles, I would always use an enum with `Flags` attribute

Comment: **ASP.NET MVC 4.0** and **ASP.NET Core** are completely different versions of ASP.NET. that are almost a decade away from each other). Please remove the question-tags that don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

use `Description` for naming enums:

```
  public enum Roles
    {
        [Description("User Create")]
        UserCreate = 1, 
        [Description("...")]
        UserEdit = 2,
        [Description("...")]
        UserDelete = 3,
        [Description("...")]
        UserAssign = 4,
        [Description("...")]
        UserView = 5, 
        [Description("...")]
        TeamsCreate = 6,
        [Description("...")]
        TeamsEdit = 7,
        [Description("...")]
        TeamsDelete = 8,
        [Description("...")]
        TeamsAssign = 9,
        [Description("...")]
        TeamsView = 10,
    }
```

use extionsion method to get names:

```
  public static string GetDescription<T>(this T e) where T : IConvertible
        {
            return
                e.GetType()
                    .GetMember(e.ToString())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    ?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
                    ?.Description ?? e.ToString();
        }
```

then use forach for view:

```
@foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues<UserRole>())
{
    <input id="@item" name="@item" type="checkbox" value="@item" />
    @item.GetDescription()
}
```